# phpunit tests - Failed asserting that two strings are equal

Tags: laravel, phpunit, currency

How is this possible?
phpunit result:

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'€ 10,00'
+'€ 10,00'
```

code:

```
$product = factory(Product::class)->create([
    'price' => 1000
]);

$this->assertEquals($product->formattedPrice, '€ 10,00');
```

I'm using this class to setup my currency and locale:
(Ommitting other functions)

```
class Money
{
    protected $money;
    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->money = new BaseMoney($value, new Currency('EUR'));
    }

    public function formatted()
    {
        $formatter = new IntlMoneyFormatter(
            new \NumberFormatter('nl_BE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY),
            new ISOCurrencies()
        );
        return $formatter->format($this->money);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the formatterPrice method or setter?

Comment: thanks for your help; added class to show how I init.

Comment: How many Asserts you have in your test method? Sometimes phpunit complaining of a wrong assertion. So maybe you are using other assertion and somehow they are causing the issue.